# How to read and change text in a TextBox control in another process in a .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, textbox, spy++

I need the following for a specific corporate application that we use in our office. The goal is to create something similar to what password managers do with forms in a web browser -- fill out the login credentials automatically. I need it only for this specific application.

When the application loads, it shows a login window:

[image]

My goal is to read `Corp Code`, `Location Code` and `User Name` & fill out the `Password` accordingly from my application that I'm writing.

I do not have the source code for the corporate application in question. I know that it is a `.NET 4.0` process:

[image]

From Windows `Spy++` I can see what those text boxes are:

[image]

So they have this `WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.*` class name, where `*` I believe can be changed from build to build:

[image]

My first instinct was to use native [`EnumWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) API with conjunction with [`GetClassName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`GetWindowText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx) to locate those text boxes and get their text, but the issue is telling them apart.

So I was hoping that their `Control ID` properties could be used for that:

[image]

but unfortunately their `Control ID` value seems to change every time the application runs.

So my only hope in this case is to identify these `TextBox` controls by their name, natively like .NET does:

[image]

Is there a way to do it from another `.NET` process?

Comment: Use UI Automation for this

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks. Any example of a source code for UI Automation. I've never used it before?

Comment: It's well documented with countless examples and tutorials. This question gets asked in a daily basis here. Rather than asking us to research for you, try using websearch yourself. You'll find that to be a really useful tool in your arsenal.

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe it is possible to expose the .NET names of the textboxes that way.  You are going down the correct path with p/invoking the `EnumWindows`, `GetClassName`, etc.

You might have luck checking the Z-Order of the child windows, which would be the effective tab order, which is probably consistent for each run.